# How to post pictures to google plus using node js

Tags: node.js, google-plus

I am trying to post a message or a picture to google plus, but I have no idea what kind of url or method should I use, please give me some advice.

Comment: First checkout the G+ API specs -> https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/

Posting content is possible with the moments resource, POST  /people/userId/moments/collection then you just write a function in node that perofrm a post action on a specific URI with params as in the specification docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Plus uses Picasa for managing photos. You can use some Picasa Module for node.js in order to upload Photos.

Here is what I've found through quick googling: https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Google/Picasa/PostPhoto/